# How to substitude a^n->D[u[t,x],{x,n}] for n=0,1,2,

Tags: replacement

I have expression which have terms

```
a, a^2, a^3, ...,
```

How can I replace

```
a^n -> D[u[t,x],{x,n}] for n=0,1,2,....
```

Comment: `{a, a^2, a^3} /. a^n_ :> D[u[t, x], {x, n}]`

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch  Mike, could you please kindly comment, why in your approach `a` is successfully replaced, while in that of V.E. it is not?

Comment: @alex i am on my phone so cannot run code. I dont think a is replaced. That is not my intention because i assumed he only wanted explicit powers replaced

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called [Replace All](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
expr = a + a^2 + a^3;    
expr /. a^n_ -> D[u[t, x], {x, n}]
```

But since a is not on the form a^1, it won't be replaced. An extra rule can be added:

```
expr /. {a^n_ -> D[u[t, x], {x, n}], a -> D[u[t, x], {x, 1}]}
```

[This page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/RearrangeTheTermsOfAPolynomial.html) shows how to extract parts from a polynomial, in case you'd like to do something with the a^0 factor too.

Comment: There is no need to define an extra rule for `a`. Adding a little dot is enough. `expr /. a^n_. :> D[u[t, x], {x, n}]` (See [Optional and Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) for explanations.)